# Bitmap Image: cropping with portrait orientation

Tags: win-universal-app, uwp

Adding camera functionality to my app is killing me!  Started with the basic UWP camera sample, but I have to add zooming capability which added a ScrollViewer around the preview control and complicated my life. Found the cropping code in a different sample.  Everything works in landscape, but when you rotate the tablet to portrait the cropped image (even without any actual cropping) is rotated 90.

The cropping logic takes originX/Y, ScrollViewer.ViewportWidth/Height & ScrollViewer.ExtentWidth/Height.   I don't understand how these values change with the rotation!  In Landscape I use topLeft for the X/Y.  What would I do for Portrait?  I'm setting the width to 400 and in both views it's STILL 400 so I don't believe width/height should be flipped.

Here's the cropping code.  Can anyone comment on what should be different for the 2 (actually 4) orientations?

```
       async public static Task<WriteableBitmap> GetCroppedBitmapAsync(StorageFile originalImageFile,
                                                 Point startPoint, Size cropSize, Size previewSize)
    {
        using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await originalImageFile.OpenReadAsync())
        {
            // Create a decoder from the stream. With the decoder, we can get the properties of the image.
            BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);

            // Adjust the start x/y to the stream size 
            uint scaledStartPointX = (uint)Math.Round((decoder.PixelWidth * (startPoint.X / previewSize.Width)));
            uint scaledStartPointY = (uint)Math.Round((decoder.PixelHeight * (startPoint.Y / previewSize.Height)));

            // Now get the scaled size of the viewport (ie the cropped area)
            uint selectedAreaWidth = (uint)Math.Round(decoder.PixelWidth * (cropSize.Width / previewSize.Width));
            uint selectedAreaHeight = (uint)Math.Round(decoder.PixelHeight * (cropSize.Height / previewSize.Height));

            // Get the cropped pixels.
            byte[] pixels = await GetPixelData(decoder, scaledStartPointX, scaledStartPointY, selectedAreaWidth, selectedAreaHeight,
                decoder.PixelWidth, decoder.PixelHeight);

            // Stream the bytes into a WriteableBitmap
            WriteableBitmap cropBmp = new WriteableBitmap((int)selectedAreaWidth, (int)selectedAreaHeight);
            Stream pixStream = cropBmp.PixelBuffer.AsStream();
            pixStream.Write(pixels, 0, (int)(selectedAreaWidth * selectedAreaHeight * 4));

            return cropBmp;
        }

    }
```